# Godot - How can I add a tooltip for my inventory?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I know you can add a tooltip using the control, but I have a inventory and it has different items. I don't think it would be practical to add 50 control nodes one for each slot but correct me if I am wrong. I want it so that if you hover over a slot it shows the stats for the item similar to Terraria's inventory tooltip system. Not sure how to do this.

Note: This same problem was asked by me [here](https://godotengine.org/qa/58037/how-can-i-add-a-tooltip-for-my-inventory), just trying to see if I can reach more people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Godot's [ItemList](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_itemlist.html) is well suited for an inventory system with many slots, and it provides a [set_item_tooltip](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_itemlist.html#class-itemlist-method-set-item-tooltip) function to add tooltips for individual items.